# Git branch relocation

Tags: git, github

Hi I have committed and pushed  some changes into root directory of my repository(Say personal_repo). Now I want them to move to inner level say
abcd/efgh inside my personal_repo. How should I proceed. I tried to do a< git branch -m current_branch abcd/efg > then pushing. ( I am very new to git so please pardon me if you find my approach insane). Pushing don't work as the directories are not there.

Please let me know how should I proceed.

Comment: I think you are confusing branches for directories, as if it were svn. In git a branch is a completely different concept from a directory and you won't be able to see them (the branches) as part of a working tree.

Comment: If you want to move somethng (file, folder) in Git, just move it and Git should track that change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know some basics about Git. You don't push changes to root repo or to a specific folder. You push change state of the whole project. Suppose you have project personal_repo which is blank initially. then you created 5 files in it e.g. a, b, c, d, e. Now you add -> commit -> push these changes ( from being empty to have 5 files) to remote repo.

Now you want to move file a to a folder AB inside this project. So you'll just create a new folder AB and move file A to AB. Again Add -> Commit -> Push these changes( 1 new folder, File A moved to AB) to remote.

If you want to perform above changes in separate branch then just create a branch and make your changes.

In real life example, suppose you have 100 apples, i gave 4 apples more and ask you total number of apples. Will you count from first apple to last apple or just add 4 apples to 100 apples?